# General solution of $\dot x=(x^2+tx+t^2)/t^2$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the scalar ODE

$$\dot x = \frac{x^2+tx+t^2}{t^2}$$

I am asked to give the "general solution" of this ODE. I understand that this is the set of all solutions to the ODE but how, exactly, do I give an answer?

Given $(t_0,x_0)\in(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\times\mathbb{R})$ I was able to show that, on some neighbourhood of $t_0$, $$x = t\tan\left(\ln(t/{t_0})-\arctan(y_0t_0)\right)$$ is the solution. Now am I right stating that $]t_0e^{c-\frac{\pi}{2}},t_0e^{c+\frac{\pi}{2}}[$ with $c=\arctan(y_0t_0)$ is the maximum existence interval and the solution is unique on this interval? Or, did I miss some details as $t$ must not be zero?

In the end, how do I give the general solution? Do I include the maximum existence interval for each $(t_0,x_0)$, or what am I meant to answer?

Comment: Indeed, $$x(t)=t\tan(\ln(t/t_0)+\arctan(x_0/t_0))$$ on the maximal interval $(t_-,t_+)$ with $$t_\pm=t_0\exp(\pm\pi/2-\arctan(x_0/t_0))$$ Is this your question?

Comment: I asked for confirmation (thanks) and about the structure of the general solution. Linear ODE's $\dot x=Ax$ allow to give as general solution a nice subset of the differentiable functions on one domain, but how am I supposed to give a general solution (as a set) in the above case? Which domains do I choose for the solutions? What is a superset of the general solution if different $(t_0,x_0)$ imply different domains for the according elements of the general solution? Or, is the general solution meant to be symbolic only, and I was not asked to think about maximum existence intervals?

Comment: The "general solution" is the formula in my post or, equivalently, $$x(t)=t\tan(c+\ln t)$$

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was wondering as my textbook did define it as the set of all solutions at some point...

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Put $$x=u t $$
then
$$x'=u+u't $$
the equation becomes

$$u+u't=u^2+u+1$$
or
$$u't=u^2+1$$

$$\frac {u'}{1+u^2}=\frac {1}{t} $$

You can take it.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is:

$$x(t) = t \tan(\ln t + \ln c).$$

Using the initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0$ ($t\neq 0$), we obtain:

$$\ln c = \arctan\frac{x_0}{t_0}-\ln t_0 \implies x(t) = t \tan(\ln \frac{t}{t_0} + \arctan\frac{x_0}{t_0})$$

This is the general solution adapted to initial conditions. The solution clearly does not exist for all $t$.